# Anyway to know when a pooled thread (or ThreadStatic member) is destroyed?

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-3.5, threadpool

I need to add a third party component to one of our products (which is a windows service that can run 24/7).
The 3PC is a .net library that sits on some hard core C++ loveliness for manipulating images.
The 3PC requires that *Initialize* and *Teardown* routines are called for every thread it runs on.
This is fine where we use it in our older software, but this product was written with the .Net thread pool, and pooled workers will exercise the 3PC. I can't figure out how to safely call the *Initialize* and *Teardown* routines.

The closest I got was when initializing a ThreadStatic member, to call the 3PC `Initialize` method, however I can't manage to call the `Teardown` on the same thread the `Initialize` was called on.

If I wrap the `Initialize` and `Teardown` in an object, with the `Teardown` called in the objects Finalize method, then the `Teardown` will be called by the GC's own Finalize thread, not the *thread* the object is *static* to (not to mention the fact that there's no guarantee the Finalizer will ever run).

Obviously I'm worried about leaked resources as the the thread pool *manages* threads under the covers, **I have no idea if or when threads will be destroyed or created**, so I've no idea how much the Service could leak over a period of time.

Anyone any ideas? Anything I've missed? Anything else to try?
Thanks

**Update**

Q: *What does Teardown do?*

I'm assuming it "Releases some memory", but I honestly have no idea. I tried splunking through the assembly with Reflector but it quickly drops from IL into native machine code. I'm going on the (3rd) party line that this must be done.

It definitely is a subsystem tear down thing.

Also, several years ago we discovered a bug around this component in another Product. The Initializer wasn't being called for every thread which resulted in some very rarely seen *Undefined behaviour*.

Comment: What does Initialize and Teardown do?  Persuading the 3PC library to function safely in a thread-agnostic manner would be best.  Especially, what does 'Teardown' do?  Does it always have to be called after some/every operation on an image or is it more of a subsystem shutdown/termination thing?

Comment: @Martin: Added more detail to the question.

Comment: Can you call `Initialize` and `Teardown` before and after every unit of work you run on the thread pool?

Comment: @Binary: You may not be able to use the `ThreadPool`, are you open to writing your own?

Comment: @Nicholas: what happens when two managed threads share the same physical thread?

Comment: @NicholasButler - that sounds risky.  If this component has 'issues', (and it certainly sounds like it does!), a good plan is not to continually make those calls.

Comment: @MartinJames Just thinking of possible solutions without re-writing the product so it doesn't use the thread pool.

Comment: @NicholasButler: Yes, but there is a significant performance hit. Also, I be wary that one physical thread could run two logical threads in the pool. At that stage you could get into a race condition that both threads Initialise, one uses and Tearsdown before the other gets to use. At that point the second displays Undefined behaviour because the 3PC isn't Initialised. **NB** _I've no idea if this is a real concern or not_ I may be worrying (I am the _Binary Worrier_ after all) about something that can't happen, I just don't know what can go on inside the thread pool.

Comment: If there was not a direct 1:1 mapping between C# pool threads and kernel threads, the documentation for C# threadpool would contain dire warnings about making blocking calls.  These warnings are not there, so the pool threads are kernel threads.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I can only assume the 3PC looks after that eventuality.

Comment: @Martin: Trust me, if I swore of using code with "issues" I'd get nothing done in here :)

Comment: AFAIK, there are no hooks available from the thread pool injection and retirement algorithm. So you cannot handle a thread retirement event. Unfortunately, it looks like you will have to provide your own thread management and refactor your project to use it.

Comment: @Nicholas: That's what I was afraid of. I can put together a _pseudo thread pool_ with a couple of utility classes. I was hoping not to introduce _another_ ThreadPool into a working application that already has a perfectly good ThreadPool.

Comment: Without actually taking apart this nasty component to find out why it needs this Initialize and Teardown stuff, (I mean, this component is off its meds:), would be to create a threadpool with a small, fixed number of threads, create a separate component instance in each one, call Initialize() at the start, (and perhaps never call Teardown).

Comment: @Martin: On the 1:1 mapping, of course you are correct . . . boy do I feel dumb right now.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - there's worse.. I know these things - boy do I feel old right now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the worst comes to the worst, and no better solution is forthcoming, you could make a threadpool of your own with a fixed number of threads, (=num of cores?).  By creating a 3PC instance in each thread and calling Initialize(), you should, hopefully, be OK.

Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsPoolApp
{


public abstract class Task {
    public EventHandler FonComplete;
    public ThreadPool myPool;
    protected int param;
    public Exception error;
    public Task(int inParam, EventHandler OnDone) { param = inParam; FonComplete = OnDone; }
    public abstract void run();
};

public class PoolThread{
private
    3PC my3PC;
    BlockingCollection<Task> FinQueue;
public
    PoolThread(BlockingCollection<Task> inQueue)
    {
       FinQueue=inQueue;
    }
    Task inMess;
    public void run(){
        my3PC = new 3PC();
        my3PC.Initialize();
        while(true){
            inMess=FinQueue.Take();
            if(inMess==null){
              my3PC.Teardown();
              return;
            }
            try
            {
                inMess.run();
                inMess.error = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                inMess.error = e;
            }
            inMess.FonComplete(inMess, null);
        }
    }
};

public class ThreadPool {
    volatile int FthreadCount;
    BlockingCollection<Task> queue;
    void startThread(){
            PoolThread thisPoolThread=new PoolThread(queue);
            Thread thisThread=new Thread(new ThreadStart(thisPoolThread.run));
            thisThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            thisThread.IsBackground = true;
            thisThread.Start();
    }
    void SetThreadCount(int newCount){
        while(FthreadCount<newCount){startThread();};
        while(FthreadCount>newCount){
            queue.Add(default(Task));
            FthreadCount--;
        };
    }
    public ThreadPool(int initThreads){
        queue=new BlockingCollection<Task>();
        for(FthreadCount=0;FthreadCount<initThreads;FthreadCount++) startThread();
    }
    public int threadCount{
        get{return FthreadCount;}
        set
        {
            while (FthreadCount < value) {
                startThread();
                FthreadCount++;
            };
            while (FthreadCount > value)
            {
                queue.Add(default(Task));
                FthreadCount--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void submit(Task task){
        task.myPool=this;
        queue.Add(task);
    }
};

}
```

To start it up, call 'new ThreadPool(numThreads);', to shut down, set the 'threadCount' property to 0.

Comment: Fix applied - original code crated 3PC in ctor - this will not work since it's then called by the creating thread. Moved ctor call to top of run() method.